# LXC container ignores etc/hosts

Tags: lxc, hosts

I'm trying to map a hostname to a ip address on a lxc container because the hostname will not be resolvable by DNS.

The lxc.conf of the container contains `lxc.mount.entry = /sas/mycontainer/etc/hosts etc/hosts none ro,bind 0 0`. Insinde the hosts file I have my ip-hostname mapping: `192.168.0.3 foo.derp`

To test the setup I ran `lxc-attach -n mycontainer -- openssl s_client -connect foo.derp:636` which returns

```
gethostbyname failure
connect:errno=0
```

I also tried to configure the mapping on the lxc host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add /etc/nsswitch.conf to the container with a `hosts: files dns` line.